# JFrame rendering off

Tags: java

I'm trying to code a game from scratch in Java but my code keeps rendering what should be completely on the screen partly off the screen.

```
public void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();

    if (bs == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, window.getWidth(), window.getHeight());
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 562, 80, 80);

    bs.show();
    g.dispose();
}
```

[image]

The window height is 642 and the square is 80 x 80, so shouldn't it fit completely into the JFrame?

Comment: You forgot the titlebar on top which is included in the calculation. You can (1) add the pixels of the top to your design-calculation or (2) remove the top-bar. In case (2) you need an additional possibility to close the screen. ALT-F4 is not the wise way to close the programm anytime :-)